# I get an error while trying to assign Dictionary<string, object> to a string variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

```
    Dictionary<string, object> myVal = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    myVal.Add("key1", "value1");
    myVal.Add("key2", "value2");
    foreach (var val in myVal)
    {
        if (val.Key == "key1")
        {
            string mystr = val.Value;
            Console.Write(val.Value);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

**I am getting this error:**

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: You are defining a dictionary with key that is a string and value that is an object (hence the `Dictionary<string, object>` why would you expect an implicit cast `string mystr = val.Value;` would work?

Comment: The beauty of using a `Dictionary<>` is that rather than loop through the keys to find what you want, you can just ask for the associated value directly. `myVal["key1"]` if you're sure the key exists, or `myVal.TryGetValue("key1", out myStr)` if you're not.

Comment: you should learn to read the error message and know right away what to do for example .. you can't store an Integer to a string without properly casting or converting it to a string.. in your case a dictionary<string, object> would never fit inside a string in laymen's terms with out proper casting..

Comment: Implicitly typing with `var mystr = val.Value;` would solve the immediate issue with this exact code, only because `Console.Write()` will use `.ToString()` on your object, but the other suggestions to use `Dictionary<string, string>` would be far better if you're that sure your values are strings. Using casting as a workaround to type-safety will run you into these sorts of probrems.

Comment: Here, I simplified it for better understanding, my object portion varies from type to type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why you are getting such Error:**

While iterating the Collection(`Dictionary<string, object>`) using `foreach (var val in myVal)` each  `val` will be a  `KeyValuePair<string, object>` where `val.Key` denotes the Key and `val.Value` denotes the Value corresponding to the key.

In your case the value will be of type `object` since your collection is of type `<string, object>`. And by using `string mystr = val.Value;` you are assigning an object to a string variable. as per rules this assignment is not permitted.

**Solution:**

- Cast the object to a string like the following:

  ```
  string mystr = (string)(val.Value);
  ```
- The statement `myVal.Add("key2", "value2");` that populates the `Dictionary` indicates that both the key and value are of string type so you can re-define the Dictionary as

  ```
  Dictionary<string, string> myVal = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  ```

Comment: Thank you, for some reason CASTING didn't work for me in my real project but it works in console app. Anyhow let me give it a retry tomorrow. 
I cannot implement Dictionary<str, str> because my data varies on the fly from type to type.

Comment: @MohammadFawadSurosh: well...! you can make a try. it will work

Answer (score 3):

Two choices:

Either use a `Dictionary<string, string>`

or

Cast the `object` instances you get out of the `Dictionary<string, object>` to a `string`

```
string mystr = (string)(val.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

my bad, I found that there are nested dictionaries and inside which another List operates that caused the issue. I just added some foreach loop to reach into the final dictionary and dig into the List which worked perfectly.

**My last piece looks as below:**

```
Messages.Add(Path.GetFileName(fileName), ((List<string>)(runResult.Single(m => m.Key == "Messages")).Value)[0]);
```